# have learned\have been learning\used to/would learn?

Tags: past-tense

> The parents **have learned** to let their kids speak.
>
> The parents **have been learning** to let their kids speak.
>
> The parents **used to/would learn** to let their kids speak.

I mean that that was certain process, they (have?) learned in the past through piece of time, for example through 3 years, and 5 years ago. They don't have to learn it anymore, because presently they can let their kids speak. But in the past they used to learn it day after day.
Or maybe another form would be right?

Comment: Why would allowing your children to speak be something that has to be learned?

Comment: @KateBunting because there are plenty parents who don't want to listen their kids. Hearing kids and understanding what they talk to us is hard job. But this is a long topic

Answer (score 0):

1 essentially means what you are trying to say.

2 suggests they are still in the process of learning it.

3 doesn't really make sense.

The simplest way to say this (aside from 1) is just:

> The parents **learned** to let their kids speak.

Learning typically takes a non-instant amount of time. It's okay to say they learned it.